# Smoothing 2-d Functions

Tags: list-manipulation, smoothing

I have a large array of triples
(x_i,y_i,f(x_i,y_i))
The the values x_i and y_i are equidistant variables and the function values f(x_i,y_i) are results of a Monte Carlo calculation  which contain some noise.

Before working further with this array I would like to smoothen the function values f(x_i,y_i) to get rid of the noise. In Mathematica I can find all sorts of smoothing algorithms for functions of one variable f(x), but not for those of two variables.

Is there a clever way to achieve this smoothing over the (x,y) plane?
U.M.

The GaussianFilter would be great, but how do I do this? My array is given in a form

```
{{x1,y1,f(x1,y1},{x1,y2,f(x1,y2}},...{x1,yn,f(x1,yn)},{x2,y1,f(x2,y1)},...
{x2,yn,f(x2,yn),......{xn,y1,f(xn,y1)},...{xn,yn,f(xn,yn)}}
```

How do apply GaussianFilter to such an array? only the f's should be smoothed, not the x and y.

Comment: What smoothing would you like? You could smoothen for every $x_i$ the series $(y_j,f(x_i,y_j))$, or for every $y_i$, the series $(x_j,f(x_j,y_i)$ for example.

Comment: An easy way could be `GaussianFilter[]`...

Comment: yes, thanks, Gaussian would smear one x after the other (for fixed y). or one y after the other, for fixed x. BUT: I would like to have a simultaneous smoothing over x and y.

Comment: No, you can apply GaussianFilter to an array! That's what you are looking for!

Comment: GaussianFilter does do 2D smoothing. If you want to implement a custom kernel, use ListConvolve which will smooth according to a user specified 2D kernel.

Comment: I want to point out, that the Gaussian filter is [separable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_blur). So the comment of user29xxx lacks mathematical knowledge. Indeed, a 2d Gaussian can be implemented by doing the two directions independently.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because what is requested comes from a misunderstanding of the problem.